# Format number using RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number like below

```
var number = '12345678904444'
```

and i want like this

```
(123) 456-7890x4444

Format is (###) ###-####x####.
```

How can i achieve this.

Comment: What you want it to capture several groups of known lengths of digits, but you don't appear to have actually tried anything. Do a Google search for Regular Expressions in Javascript.

Comment: This isn't really what I would use RegExp for tbh

Comment: I googled it.. But i dont have any idea. How can i achieve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is what RegExp solution would look like ;-)

```
number.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/, '($1) $2-$3x$4.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript string split method :

```
var number = '12345678904444';
var numbers_array = numbers.split("");
```

Then you can use the array of the numbers to create a new string, following the format you want.

I'm sure you can do that !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format a number in Javascript, your best bet is to use `String.slice()` to extract the number parts you need, then contact them together using `+`.

DO NOT USE REGEX FOR THIS!! If your string in this has an error and can't be parsed properly, you run the risk of catastrophic backtracking, where your processing lasts really, really long.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this:

```
var num = '1234567890x4444';
var first = num.substr(0,3), second = num.substr(3,3), last = num.substr(6);
var formatted = '('+first+') ' + second + '-'+ last;
```

Result:

```
console.log(formatted); // (123) 456-7890x4444
```